# How to save multiple line of text file to another text file

Tags: shell

I have text file with logs like this :

234,jfksdshdfjsfds
243,jkajdskasjdlada
543,adjsaskdjaksjda

How to create and store lines with same id in different folders using Shell. Id is number in front of every line.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk -F, '{fn=$1".txt"}{print >> fn;close(fn)}' log.file
```

The above codes explained itself actually:

- save the `$1`.txt as filename in var `fn`
- append the current line to `fn` file
- close `fn` file
- pick next line...

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram added. For some codes with very simple logic, the code explains itself. IMO.

Comment: I agree with you thats just a suggestion